# How to GUI programming with embedded plots in C++?

Tags: c++, user-interface

I want to make a GUI application that I would like it to have a bar plot, pie graph (or simple plot a curve) embedded to it. I don't want it to rely on other application to do this. Also, I would like the source code to be portable. Can I use GTK+ for this? is there some sort of a library that I can include (and use) in my code for this? what are the alternatives?

I'm just looking for an answer that points me in the right direction, and start building some knowledge from there.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765408/c-free-easy-way-to-draw-graphs-and-charts for some charting libraries that may match your requirements.

Comment: This depends on the GUI library you want to use. Qt? Gtk?

Comment: I'm thinking of using GTK+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did use **[FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/)** which is a lightweight cross-plateform C++ GUI framework. It is foremost a UI toolkit, but you can also do a wide variety of graphs :

- bar chart : http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk/#Fl_Chart
- 3D : http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk/#OpenGlTextOn3D
- bar graph : http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk/#MultiColorBarGraph

There is also a Drawing module, which can plot Bezier curves and basic geometric shapes such as triangles, boxes and circles.

However, the documentation is not very helpful (from my experience) so try to adapt examples to your needs : **http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk** and **http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/examples.html**