# How to plot data by c program?

Tags: c, graph, plot, gnuplot, simulation

I am a mechanical engineer who has only limited knowledge in C programming. I wrote some code in order to make simulations, and I want to visualize the simulation results. At the moment I am using `Dev-C` for writing my codes. With `fopen` and `fprintf` commands I generate a `.dat` file which includes the results. Then I open `GNUPLOT` program and import my `.dat` file to plot the results. This takes time and I have to wait till the end of the simulation. Is there an easy way to connect my plotter with `Dev-C`, so my plotter starts plotting data during the simulation? Any library or etc. ?

Comment: Do you have data to plot if the simulation isn't done?

Comment: What exactly takes time? Manually executing `gnuplot` and importing the data? Or does `gnuplot` itself take a lot of time plotting it? If its the first, you could easily get rid of it by executing `gnuplot` from the simulator itself. e.g. in POSIX-likes, there is the [`exec` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/exec.html).

Comment: I wonder if you couldn't use a pipe instead of a file.

Comment: As I know, such popular plotting libraries like gnuplot & mathGL needs all data be ready before plotting.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for replying.
I will give quick info. The thing what takes time is everytime writing the gnuplot commands manually. By some commands I wrote in my C programs, I want gnuplot to automatically plot my data. Since it is hard, it is not really important whether during or end of simulation...

Since the other things I read here, I am working on "_popen" command. But by somehow the program says: "popen undeclared (first use in this function)". (I am using win7 and I added #include <stdio.h>) Any ideas?

Answer (score 21):

Since you already know gnuplot, the simplest thing to do may be to just call gnuplot from your program and pipe the data to it:

```
FILE *gnuplot = popen("gnuplot", "w");
fprintf(gnuplot, "plot '-'\n");
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    fprintf(gnuplot, "%g %g\n", x[i], y[i]);
fprintf(gnuplot, "e\n");
fflush(gnuplot);
```

Comment: I've used this one in a unix environment and when using cygwin on windows.  It always worked for me :).

Comment: @Edgar
Hi Edgar, thanks for answer. Calling gnuplot from my program and piping the data to it is exactly what I want to do. I added your code into my program (ofcourse I also changed X[i] and y[i]). But I got this compiling error: "'popen' undecleared (first use in this function). I am using Win 7, do you have any idea why I got this error?
Thanks.

Comment: Since popen() is POSIX, on Windows you may try with an underscore: _popen().

Comment: @Edgar,
That also doesn't work. The code you wrote seems the easiest approach to my goal but I can't compile it :)

Comment: Prepending `set nokey;` to plot removes the annoying legend.

Answer (score 5):

I've been using [PLPlot](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/) for plotting from C and have found it both effective and easy.  It's cross platform, open source, and supports a rich array of plot capabilities.  I'd recommend having a look at the examples to get started.

Answer (score 4):

OK, one solution, as you are writing out to a file, would be to just make a `system()` call when you write out to the file, and call gnuplot.

But, that means you should change the filename each time, but I fear if you do that that it won't look correct, since you are sending small amounts of data each time.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/System-Calls.html

I have never used gnuplot, but if you look at this page (http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/) you may find some tricks that would enable this to work well.

But, I think, unless you are going to plot everything yourself, and skip gnuplot, then you may just need to wait, as you are.

You may find the C interface to gnuplot may help you:

http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/

Answer (score 3):

pbPlots is very easy to use and works with all C compilers.

Download pbPlots.c/h and supportLib.c/h from the [github page](https://github.com/InductiveComputerScience/pbPlots/tree/v0.1.7.1) and include them in your build.

Here is a complete example that will produce a plot in a PNG-file.

```
#include "pbPlots.h"
#include "supportLib.h"

int main(){

    double x [] = {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    double y [] = {-5, -4, -3, -2, 1, 0, 1, 2};

    RGBABitmapImageReference *imageRef = CreateRGBABitmapImageReference();

    DrawScatterPlot(imageRef, 600, 400, x, 8, y, 8);

    size_t length;
    double *pngData = ConvertToPNG(&length, imageRef->image);
    WriteToFile(pngData, length, "plot.png");

    return 0;
 }
```

[image: the generated plot]

There are a lot more options available, these are described on the github page.

Comment: I added the pbPlots.c/h and supportLib.c/h files to a CLion project but when I try to run your example I get an error: C:/Users/flori/CLionProjects/Plottest/main.c:9: undefined reference to `CreateRGBABitmapImageReference' (+ a lot more unresolved references)
... what did I do wrong ?

Comment: @le_lemon, did you include pbPlots.c and supportLib.c in the build? In C, the compiler uses the .h-files while the linker uses the .c files. The linker needs to know which C files are included. The error comes form the linker not getting the compiled .c-files.

Comment: @MartinJohansen are you the author?

Comment: @ChefGladiator, yes, I am the author.

Answer (score 1):

There is a extensive library called DISLIN for scientific purpose. Avaliable even in Fortran language.

You can check examples in official website.

You can obtain it freely in [DISLIN Homepage](https://www.mps.mpg.de/dislin)

Comment: Please explain how this relates to the question and how it works.

Comment: @m-chen-3 You can find set of examples at [Dislin examples](https://www.mps.mpg.de/dislin/examples). Just click one of plot tutorial then select your language (C).

Answer (score 0):

I had a wee look around to see what other people have done regarding real-time plotting in gnuplot, and found this:

http://users.softlab.ntua.gr/~ttsiod/gnuplotStreaming.html

There's a little Perl script that can drive the plotting, and you just pipe your information in.

Since your data is being written to file, you may want to `tail -f yourdata.dat` and pipe that into the real-time plotter.

Also, because you're using the stdio file calls, you'd need to flush regularly (by calling `fflush`)

Obviously your simulation would be running in the background or in another shell.  That way you could break out of the plotting at any time without interrupting the simulation.

Hope that's of some use to you.

Comment: Hi Paddy, thanks for answer. I checked the webpage you linked. Actually I was using this method (preparing make file, bash file) during my master work in a company. THere we were using Linux and the programs were all set by IT. Now in my personal computer I use Windows, so I need to learn everything (with my poor knowledge) this time for windows platform. Is there anyway to do those things in windows?

Comment: The most promising way is to install Cygwin, but you could have a crack at installing Perl for Windows.  There's a ported version kicking around.  It's nice if you can stick to the tools and methods that you know rather than learn a whole new (crippled, in the case of Windows) toolset.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step solution to plot using C programming language:

Step 1 requirements: 1. Windows 10/11 64bit 2. [Install](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) eclipse IDE (CDT or scientific computing) 3.Install MSYS2 4. [Install](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) `mingw64` required component for c compiler using MSYS2 and adding it's binary path to windows environment variable 5. Install `mathgl` library using MSYS2:
[image: Installing mathgl]

Step 2 Crete eclipse project witch includes required `mathgl` required library.
[image: Create library]
Add required library to project:

Right click on the project -> Expand C/C++ Build -> Setting -> Expand MinGW C Linker (if wasn't expanded) -> Libraries -> Libraries (-l) -> add...

Here you must add `mgl2` and `mgl2-fltk`:
[image: library inclution]
Step 3 (final) Writing a code to plot: create a .c file under project and write the below code to it.

```
#include <mgl2/mgl_cf.h>
//#include <mgl2/wnd_cf.h>
#include <mgl2/fltk.h>

#include <synchapi.h>



HMGL gr = NULL;//HMGL mgl_create_graph_fltk

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{

gr = mgl_create_graph_fltk(NULL, "First C graph", NULL, NULL);

double x[50]={0};
HMDT dat=mgl_create_data_size(50, 1, 1);

while(1)
{
    Sleep(100);
    mgl_clf ( gr) ;
    mgl_set_range_val(gr, 'y', -1, 1);
    mgl_set_range_val(gr, 'x', 0, 512);
    mgl_set_origin(gr, 0, 0, 0);
//  mgl_box(gr);
    mgl_axis(gr, "", "", "");
    mgl_set_font_size(gr, 1.5);
//  mgl_grid(gr, a, "", "");




    int i=0;
    while(i<50)
    {
        x[i]=(mgl_rnd()*2)-1;
        i++;
    }

    mgl_data_set_double(dat, x, 50, 1, 1);
//  mgl_line(gr,0,0,0,2*mgl_rnd()-1,2*mgl_rnd()-1,0,"Ar2",-.5);
    mgl_stem(gr, dat, "ro", "");


//   mgl_wnd_update(gr);
}
return 0;
}
```

After building this code, you will find an executable included in the debug folder.